# Why doesn't work this query ( MongoDB )

Tags: mongodb

i have the following model:

```
   {
"_id" : ObjectId("552ea1cd4ad5dbf56bf9b0ff"),
"nro_socio" : 112323,
"nombre" : "Martina Pardo",
"apellido " : "Biroccio",
"dni " : "27465789",
"direccion " : "Av. Rivadavia 123 1ro A",
"deporte " : [
    "RUGBY",
    "FUTBOL",
    "TENNIS"
],
"cuotas" : [
    {
        "nro_cuota" : 1,
        "fecha_emision" : ISODate("2015-03-10T06:01:17.171Z"),
        "fecha_vencimiento " : ISODate("2015-04-01T06:01:17.171Z"),
        "importe " : 325,
        "fecha_pago " : ISODate("2015-03-19T06:01:17.171Z")
    },
    {
        "nro_cuota " : 2,
        "fecha_emision " : ISODate("2015-04-10T06:01:17.171Z"),
        "fecha_vencimiento " : ISODate("2015-05-01T06:01:17.171Z"),
        "importe " : 325,
        "fecha_pago " : ISODate("2015-04-19T06:01:17.171Z")
    }
]
```

}

When i do: 
`db.socios.find({"cuotas.nro_cuota":1},{nombre:1}).pretty()`

Its find the document: 
`{ "_id" : ObjectId("552ea1cd4ad5dbf56bf9b0ff"), "nombre" : "Martina     Pardo" }`

When i do:
`db.socios.find({"cuotas.nro_cuota":2},{nombre:1}).pretty()`

I doesn't.
Anyone know why? Its the same query, only changed the number...

I should retrieve the same document, right?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same query but you have different keys, the other key in the second array  has a space at the end. So if you do

```
db.socios.find({"cuotas.nro_cuota ":2},{nombre:1}).pretty()
```

You will get a match.

Answer (score 0):

It is because "cuotas" is an array. You need to use elemMatch. Look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#array-of-embedded-documents

```
db.socios.find({ "cuotas": { $elemMatch: { "nro_cuota": 2 } } }, {nombre:1})
```